# Meaning of "turned it on its head"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I got the below mentioned line from the site 'erikalust.com/films/the-good-girl'

`Erika Lust’s indie debut burst onto the scene of adult cinema and turned it on its head.`

May one explain me what the last part of the sentence (turned it on its head) mean?

Comment: ***Turn on its head***: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+on+its+head

Comment: @Ravi You could have just googled it yourself. Such questions are not fit for the site. But if you already found the meaning and have doubts, you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per oxford dictionary **turn something on its head** means-

> Completely reverse the principles or interpretation of an idea or argument.

As per [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_on_its_head-)

> **1**.(transitive, idiomatic) **To turn upside-down**; **to invert**.
>
> The crisis **turned on their head** the formulas that had seemed to work.
>
> **2**.(transitive, idiomatic) **To completely change**.
>
> The global economic crisis has managed to **turn on their head** stock exchanges worldwide.